# leaflet marker not showing when i import leaflet.css from node_modules

Tags: reactjs, leaflet

I have this method to add marker to map

```
createMarker(map) {
    if (this.state.node !== undefined) {
        const nodeLength = this.state.node.length;
        const latLang = [];
        this.state.node.map(item => latLang.push([item.latitude, item.longitude]));
        this.marker = [];

        // looping node
        for (let i = 0; i < nodeLength; i++) {
            this.marker[i] = L.marker(latLang[i]).addTo(map).on('click', () => this.handleClick(i));
        }
    } else {
        return 0;
    }
}
```

it's showing when i'm using this in index.html

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.6.0/dist/leaflet.css" integrity="sha512-xwE/Az9zrjBIphAcBb3F6JVqxf46+CDLwfLMHloNu6KEQCAWi6HcDUbeOfBIptF7tcCzusKFjFw2yuvEpDL9wQ==" crossorigin=""/>
```

but when i import it in index.js its now showing

```
import "leaflet/dist/leaflet.css"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is an already existing issue with webpack and the bundling of files during building, check [#4968](https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet/issues/4968).

to overcome this issue, create a  marker with a custom icon as an L.icon instance like this:

```
....
const icon = L.icon({
  iconSize: [25, 41],
  iconAnchor: [10, 41],
  popupAnchor: [2, -40],
  iconUrl: "https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.6/dist/images/marker-icon.png",
  shadowUrl: "https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.6/dist/images/marker-shadow.png"
});

...

createMarker(map) {
    if (this.state.node !== undefined) {
        const nodeLength = this.state.node.length;
        const latLang = [];
        this.state.node.map(item => latLang.push([item.latitude, item.longitude]));
        this.marker = [];

        // looping node
        for (let i = 0; i < nodeLength; i++) {
            this.marker[i] = L.marker(latLang[i], { icon }) // here pass icon as an option when creating markers
                                     .addTo(map)
                                     .on('click', () => this.handleClick(i));
        }
    } else {
        return 0;
    }
}
```